# Create a batch file to toggle control panel settings - "When I close the lid:"

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, sleep

When I have my laptop (Windows 10) plugged into my monitor, I like to keep the lid closed. I can do this by changing the settings circled in the snapshot at the bottom of this Q. When not plugged into the monitor, I prefer that the computer sleeps when the lid is closed.

Is there an easy way to change these settings through a batch script? It doesn't have to be a toggle; could have one script to change to "Do Nothing" and one to change to "Sleep".

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an untested example script for you to try:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%powercfg.exe" -SetDCValueIndex Scheme_Current 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 1
@"%__AppDir__%powercfg.exe" -SetACValueIndex Scheme_Current 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 0
@"%__AppDir__%powercfg.exe" -SetActive Scheme_Current
```

The first command sets the `current` power configuration `When I close the lid` and `On battery` to `Sleep`. The second line sets the `current` power configuration `When I close the lid` and `Plugged in` to `Do nothing`. The third line activates the new settings.

**[Edit /]**

Based upon your comment regarding the GUID's, I have decided to add the below answer, which uses their aliases instead. *You can find out those aliases along with their respective GUID's by entering `"%__AppDir__%powercfg.exe" /Aliases` at the Command Prompt.*

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%powercfg.exe" -SetDCValueIndex Scheme_Current Sub_Buttons LidAction 1
@"%__AppDir__%powercfg.exe" -SetACValueIndex Scheme_Current Sub_Buttons LidAction 0
@"%__AppDir__%powercfg.exe" -SetActive Scheme_Current
```

Comment: Hey it worked, thank you so much! How do you figure out these commands and more curiously, the obscure (I assume hex address?) code following?
I believe you have it mixed up with AC and DC: AC (first line) is plugged in, DC  (second line) is on battery.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my mistake, I corrected it by changing the code order, _because it was quicker than changing the body text_. Incidentally, you don't really need to know the GUID's, as aliases can be used for those too, *please see my latest **[Edit /]***

Comment: Can I use a variable for Scheme_Current or is it not possible because it is more like a enum or constant than a string.

Comment: @Timo, could you please expand on your comment, I need you to put it into the context of a batch file task, to determine if  it is a separate question you should ask as a new question, or something I can incorporate into this answer.

Comment: Maybe I should ask a new question because my issue is related to Powershell, not bat. I wonder if I can do `$var=Scheme_Current; powercfg -SetDCValueIndex $var ..`